# Cannot Link Access Form to Dataset

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access Form which uses a SQL server as it's data source.  I want to give the user the option of filtering the form using the form ID number.  I have created the controls to capture the ID Number and I am using the code below to get the data.

```
Dim strReq As String
        strReq = Me.txtSearchTerm
           StrSql = "SELECT tblOrders.*, tblFleetVendors.* FROM tblOrders"
           StrSql = StrSql + "INNER JOIN tblFleetVendors ON tblOrders.VendorId = tblFleetVendors.VendorID"
           StrSql = StrSql + "WHERE tblOrders.VendorId<>774 'AND tblOrders.OrderID =" & strReq & "));"
            Set db = CurrentDb()
            Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryOrders")
            qdf.SQL = StrSql
            Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qryOrders", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
            intRecords = rst.RecordCount
            If intRecords <= 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no records that match your search"
            rst.Close
            Set rst = Nothing
            Set db = Nothing
            rst.Close
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            Exit Sub
            Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDataEntry"
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMainMenu"
            End If
```

My code runs and I retrieve 1 record from the SQL data.  My problem is I cannot figure out how to use the data to populate the form. Can anyone explain how I can use this data to populate the form?

Comment: Make `qryOrders` the record source of your form.

Comment: As Andre suggests, if you open frmDataEntry in Design View and set its RecordSource property to qryOrders (save the form with this property set), the  code above should work. If this i a pass through query, and because you named the variable "strReq", you may want to put it in single quotes: AND tblOrders.OrderID ='" & strReq & "'

Comment: Need to include space at end or beginning of each StrSQL line so strings won't run together when concatenated.

Comment: Thanks I inherited this project and do not have a lot of experience with the Access VB syntax can you give an example of setting the forms record source?  I used this                 Forms!frmDataEntry.RecordSource = "qryOrders" the compiles and ran but did not return the proper record set

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the order I was I did not bind the form to the data.  The SQL query was doing it's job I was not applying it as the forms data source.  The working code is shown below.

```
Case "Req"
        Me.cmdDone.SetFocus
        GotoSearchTextbox
        If IsNull(Me.txtSearchTerm) Then 'Blank, show them all!
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDataEntry"
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMainMenu"
        Else
        Dim Req As Integer 'OrderId entered  do the search
        Req = Me.txtSearchTerm
         StrSql = "SELECT tblOrders.*, tblFleetVendors.* FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblFleetVendors ON tblOrders.VendorId = tblFleetVendors.VendorID"
         StrSql = StrSql & " WHERE (((tblOrders.Org)=DLookUp(""[DivisionOrg]"",""tblSetup""))"
         StrSql = StrSql & "AND ((tblOrders.VendorId)<>774) AND ((tblOrders.OrderID)=" & Req & "));"
            Set db = CurrentDb()
            Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryOrders")
            qdf.SQL = StrSql
            Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qryOrders", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
            intRecords = rst.RecordCount
            If intRecords <= 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no records that match your search"
            Set rst = Nothing
            Set db = Nothing
            rst.Close
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            Exit Sub
            Else
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDataEntry"
            Form!frmDataEntry.RecordSource = StrSql
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMainMenu"
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use what is called a "where" clause of the form.
(do not confuse with  the filter option on open - don't use that).

So you can do this:

```
dim strWhere    as string
strWhere = "tblOrders.VendorId <> 774 AND tblOrders.OrderID = " & strReq

docmd.OpenForm "frmDataEntry",,,strWhere
```

So, if the form has a vendorID an da orderid, then the form will open to the ONE reocrd.
Of course you can add your other code, but the two lines of code to filter/set and open the form to the ONE record based on the "where" clause can be done as per above.

You don't really have to build a new query or do really much of anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer when I made this change to the code I get a blank screen any idea why and a fix?

Comment: Well, if you click  on the form from the nave pane without any code, then the form should always show all records - that takes zero code to test and try. If your form is not showing all the records when you opened it, designed it and been using a good working known form? Well then of course it not going to work if you try opening with code, or in this case opening with code and  also adding a "where" clause. So, get the form working as normal - that means you just open the form and  it  shows all records based on the linked table it is bound  to. Such a test takes zero code to try.